# About clang AST and odr-use of destructors

Tags: c++, clang, destructor, one-definition-rule, libtooling

For the following code

```cpp
struct X {
  int a;
};

int main() {
  X x;
  return 0;
}
```

The clang AST does not show a `DestructorDecl`:

```
CXXRecordDecl 0x55a415f54f00 </home/gkxx/exercises/smfgen/tmp/../tmp/a.cpp:1:1, line:4:1> line:1:8 referenced struct X definition
|-DefinitionData pass_in_registers aggregate standard_layout trivially_copyable pod trivial literal
| |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial
| |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param implicit_has_const_param
| |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial
| |-CopyAssignment simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
| |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
| `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
|-CXXRecordDecl 0x55a415f55018 <col:1, col:8> col:8 implicit struct X
|-FieldDecl 0x55a415f550c0 <line:2:3, col:7> col:7 a 'int'
|-CXXConstructorDecl 0x55a415f55320 <line:1:8> col:8 implicit used X 'void () noexcept' inline default trivial
| `-CompoundStmt 0x55a415f557d8 <col:8>
|-CXXConstructorDecl 0x55a415f55458 <col:8> col:8 implicit constexpr X 'void (const X &)' inline default trivial noexcept-unevaluated 0x55a415f55458
| `-ParmVarDecl 0x55a415f55568 <col:8> col:8 'const X &'
`-CXXConstructorDecl 0x55a415f55618 <col:8> col:8 implicit constexpr X 'void (X &&)' inline default trivial noexcept-unevaluated 0x55a415f55618
  `-ParmVarDecl 0x55a415f55728 <col:8> col:8 'X &&'
```

I tried to get the `CXXRecordDecl` of `struct X` and found that `decl->getDestructor()` returns `nullptr`.

This makes me a little bit confused, because the standard says that a class without a user-declared destructor will have an implicilty-declared one, **and it will be implicitly-defined when odr-used.** So what is an odr-used destructor? Is the destructor of this `X` odr-used? Or is this just about my misunderstanding of clang AST and the behavior of `clang::CXXRecordDecl::getDestructor`?

Note that in contrast, the clang-AST shows that the default constructor of `X` is defined, even though it does not do anything.

Comment: The "trivial" things do nothing and so may be left not called. But existence of default constructor itself is important fact (even when trivial).

Comment: As the question pertains to the clang "libtooling" C++ API, I've added that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is this destructor ODR-used?

Yes.  Quoting [basic.def.odr](https://wg21.link/basic.def.odr#9):

> A destructor for a class is odr-used if it is potentially invoked.

where "potentially invoked" has a non-trivial definition, but in short,
is true here because `main()` declares an object of type `X`.

### What does it mean that Clang `getDestructor()` is `nullptr`?

The documentation of
[`CXXRecordDecl::getDestructor()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html#ac87a7cb3291953bb9762bd31ad5d686d)
just says:

> Returns the destructor decl for this class.

without even acknowledging that it can return `nullptr`, let alone
explaining what that would mean.  Based on reading the source, I
conclude it means the destructor is trivial, *and* that none of the
conditions that would cause an implicit declaration to be created anyway
(see below) have been satisfied.

It does *not* mean that Clang is claiming the destructor is not
ODR-used.  The
[`Decl::isUsed()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html#abbddfbe509cc5ff01b53a556e063ed7c)
method claims to report this information (see documentation on
`setIsUsed()`), but it does not appear to be completely accurate; even
if I cause the destructor declaration to be created by adding a
`virtual` function, the destructor is still not marked `isUsed()`.

### Doesn't the standard say the destructor should be defined here?

Yes--but to be conforming, Clang only needs to produce compiled output
that acts "as if" the destructor had been defined.  The absence of a
particular AST node doesn't make it non-conforming.  Even the lack of a
definition in the compiled object file doesn't, so long as it adheres to
the relevant ABI, thereby cooperating with other tools, to again achieve
the required "as if" behavior (under the assumption that the source code
complies with the One Definition Rule).

### What are the conditions for Clang to create an implicit declaration?

This doesn't appear to be documented, so I tried to figure it out from
the source.  An implicit destructor declaration is created by
`Sema::DeclareImplicitDestructor()` at
[`SemaDeclCXX.cpp:13803`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclCXX.cpp#L13803).
This function is called in several places, and I didn't follow all of
the chains backward, but to a first approximation, this will not be
called if:

- the destructor itself is trivial, and
- the class does not have a vtable, and
- no overload resolution among destructors is required (which might
  be needed for `requires`).

Note that it is that last condition, overload resolution due to the
declaration of `x`, that causes Clang to declare the three implicit
**con**structors.

### Can I force the destructor to be declared anyway?

Yes!  You can call
[`Sema::ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Sema.html#a13e40364e7b40a2311e03d010610bd34)
on a `CXXRecordDecl` to force Clang to declare the implicit members even
if it would not have done so otherwise.  For instance, right after
parsing, you can use a
[`RecursiveASTVisitor`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html)
to walk the AST and call this method on every `CXXRecordDecl`.

After doing that, all of the implicit members will be available.

### How would I get a `Sema` object?

You cannot get it from an `ASTContext` because that is just the AST,
whereas `Sema` is part of the process for *creating* the AST.  (If you
were to save the AST to disk and then load it back, there would not be a
`Sema` object at all.)

My preferred approach is to use
[`ASTUnit::LoadFromCompilerInvocation`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html#ab4a8991c0faa89d3cb83d58f581a1097)
to do the initial parse.  That yields an `ASTUnit` object immediately,
from which you can get both the `Sema` (via `getSema()`) and the
`ASTContext` (via `getASTContext()`).

If you are instead using
[`ClangTool::run`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1ClangTool.html),
which is what the
[tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html)
points people at:

```
Tool.run(
  clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory<MyASTFrontendAction>().get());
```

Grab the `CompilerInstance` in `CreateASTConsumer`:

```
class MyASTFrontendAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
  virtual unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
    clang::CompilerInstance &ci,
    llvm::StringRef inFile) override
  {
    return make_unique<MyASTConsumer>(ci);
  }
};
```

Then store it in the `ASTConsumer`, and use its `getSema()` when needed:

```
class MyASTConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer {
public:
  clang::CompilerInstance &m_compilerInstance;

  MyASTConsumer(clang::CompilerInstance &compilerInstance)
    : m_compilerInstance(compilerInstance)
  {}

  virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext &Context) override
  {
    clang::Sema &sema = m_compilerInstance.getSema();

    // ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answers for my two questions! `The documentation of CXXRecordDecl::getDestructor() just says "Returns the destructor decl for this class." without even acknowledging that it can return nullptr, let alone explaining what that would mean.` Yes, I think the documentations (and the [tutorials](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html)) are really brief and abstract. So did you find out all these things mainly by reading the source code? Could you please recommend me some friendlier related materials for learning the clang libtoolling? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!  I primarily learned this by reading what documentation there is, digging through the source, and experimentation.  If you haven't, check out [the internals manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html), which has some good info.  Beyond that, I'm in the process of writing additional docs: [Clang PR 66436](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/66436).

Comment: I found it much easier (I mean, with less refactoring) to get the Sema object by simply calling `getSema()` on a `CompilerInstance`, which can be obtained in `ASTFrontendAction::CreateASTConsumer`.

Comment: Now the implicit-declarations are generated by `Sema::ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers`, but those that the standard requires to be implicitly-defined may still not be defined. I found the functions named `Sema::DefineImplicitxxx` which can be used to define them, but how can I determine whether a special member function is odr-used? I also found the function `Sema::getUndefinedButUsed()`, but it seems to generate an empty vector in this case.

Comment: @GKxx Thanks for the tip on `CompilerInstance`; I had missed that route through the API (answer edited accordingly).  As for determining odr-usage, the only thing I am aware of is `Decl::isUsed()`, but it does not seem to be accurate (or maybe I misunderstand ord-usage or that API's purpose).  I suggest asking a new question specifically about getting odr-usage from the Clang API for these destructor cases.

Comment: As for determining odr-usage of destructor, is it possible to manually match all objects with static/thread/automatic storage duration, all temporary objects, and all objects that are destroyed by `delete` over the whole AST? I think the constructors and assignment operators always need overload resolution (so they are always defined when odr-used), so we only need to consider the destructor case.

Comment: @GKxx Yes, finding all those cases individually is possible, or at least I'm not aware of any barriers to doing so.  There is at least one other case that calls dtors though: if an exception is thrown from a ctor then dtors for the already-constructed fields and base class subobjects get called.